# Flattening type that gives a union of all keys in a nested object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I feel like this should not be so difficult. Yet, no matter what I try, I can't get it to work. Here's the best I got so far:

```js
// Sample type. I want to make this into 'a' | 'b' | 'x' | 'c' | 'd'
type O = Record<'a', Record<'b' | 'x', Record<'c' | 'd', string | number>>>;

// Explicit way of doing it, with limited depth
type Explicit = keyof O | keyof O[keyof O] | keyof O[keyof O][keyof O[keyof O]];

// What I hoped would work
type ExtractKeys<T> = T extends Record<infer U, any> ?
  keyof T | ExtractKeys<T[U]> :
  never;

// Or
type ExtractKeys2<T> = T extends Record<string, any> ?
  keyof T | ExtractKeys<T[keyof T]> :
  never;

// Try it
// TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
const tryIt: ExtractKeys<O> = 'a';

// Can assign anything
const tryIt2: ExtractKeys2<O> = 'z';
```

The error is quite clear, I'm somehow ending up with infinite recursion. Yet I really do not see how? Nor do I find a better way. Any ideas?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/PTAEGUEMFsAcBsCmoAuBPWiB0oCSoB3SAOxVQHtRpIBrZFACwEsBnUJ0ygcki9AB9QXAEZ9BXAB5ihAY2lcAJlwBQ6TKADyoALygASohnkATgoA8PLgBp9hk+ZHypNg0dMW5AoUpssUxjgBzL2IAV2hhRGMAPliAbmVlEFAAUQkEJhkmMiI0UHIAM1AFciD2FBsCbIZQeCZobMQFYsRYRlUMZDSMrLJdOjRCzS8BoY0AbVGijQBdEcRB6cmFsZnlxc111ZmEpLAAdQZIMnwGckxmgnJQ+EuTGg71NP9IGRQAaQWWMwAVaJ1QD9QIgJChEMQFGxXPYzBwClFQABVGwkND-AD8ylAoCmgK8z2Mrw+X1+40RM3+AC4saBiIgAG5RXbJDTGR5dUGEt6fNAsABMv3+uiBILBEKhdncfgCxECKOIaNAmOxuKBggJRJ53x+WyKPwpoGp2LpjOMzLAP2MeWye0B4D5AFYABwATkpgM67GIfhIKCYxyY5GI7DYIJkiBYLCYjPgeQUiFaoBIzVg5EjTGEsa9BQ4jSwyiM3rI-jQuBQ7o13JJGiFQl45tAAGESEn04Fg6jGEEC0G-KgrWW+RXOZqvgKawCuAAvLhxIA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had a typo in `EtractKeys2`. You used `EtractKeys` instead of `ExtractKeys2` for your recursive call.

```
type ExtractKeys2<T> = T extends Record<string, any> 
  ? keyof T | ExtractKeys2<T[keyof T]> 
  : never

const tryIt2: ExtractKeys2<O> = 'z';
```

This works now.

---

Your first method failed because of the `infer U`. This check actually returns `true` for primitives.

```
type Test1 = number extends Record<string, any> ? true : false
//   ^? false

type Test2 = number extends Record<infer U, any> ? true : false
//   ^? true
```

Since this is always `true`, you end up with an infinite loop causing the *"Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite"* error.

Interestingly you end up with `keyof Number` with this inference.

```
type Test3 = number extends Record<infer U, any> ? U : false
//   ^? keyof Number
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=21&pln=14&pc=1#code/PTAEGUEMFsAcBsCmoAuBPWiB0oCSoB3SAOxVQHtRpIBrZFACwEsBnUJ0ygcki9AB9QXAEZ9BXAB5ihAY2lcAJlwBQ6TKADyoALygASohnkATgoA8PLgBp9hk%20ZHypNg0dMW5AoUpssUxjgBzL2IAV2hhRGMAPliAbmVlEFAAUQkEJhkmMiI0UHIAM1AFciD2FBsCbIZQeCZobMQFYsRYRlUMZDSMrLJdOjRCzS8BoY0AbVGijQBdEcRB6cmFsZnlxc111ZmExLVkABVEPwBGHVAwiKjQRAkURGIFNld7Mz8A4kCbEjRo0AB%20VDGULIABcoAKkHgLEQSTAoFAAD1AZDobCOuojn4AEznS6RYw3O4PJ62NzmDgFa4AVW%20xF%20AKBINA4NRMLhCKRgP8IL2nVAWJQAGY8eECUT7o9nnZ3JSaXSGYDqSyIVD2ckEcjQFNQAA5MVRRIYrp3YyQGQoADSCxYZgOf10BwlJOl5LMcsJytuktJ7yCCr%20-2UCJ1TsEaX85qtNrt42pMz%20oODF0QADcorsjMQ-EC0LgUOCI2aLda0LaNA6hLxdhyNMZjalTVHSyxsXbK07vS6ya8-Z8AwDk6GvEXmza2wctkUDgmWcniGmM0aszn-HmUNjC02S%20OzBXzlwAF5cOJAA)

Comment: Follow up: Why does `type ExtractKeys<T> = T extends object ? keyof T | ExtractKeys<T[keyof T]> : never;`, which could easily give just `never` if one isn't careful, work, while `type ExtractKeys2<T extends object> = keyof T | (T[keyof T] extends object ? ExtractKeys2<T[keyof T]> : never);`, which is designed more carefully, does not?

Comment: I tried to debug this but I can't seem to figure it out :/ ... no clue

Comment: Haha, okay, I'm weirdly glad to hear that. Thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you want to have a type that returns all the keys of the given object type and its object properties.

If this is the case, the following could be a possible approach:

```
export type Keys<T extends object> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Keys<T[K]> | K : K
}[keyof T]

interface User {
    name: {
        first: string
        last: string
    }
}

const x: Keys<User> = 'first' // 'last', 'name'
```

```
type O = Record<'a', Record<'b' | 'x', Record<'c' | 'd', string | number>>>;

const o: Keys<O> = 'a' // 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x'
```

---

## Explanation

Here, I map each key of `T` to the key type `K` itself. If the value of `T[K]`, which is the key's value, should be an object, I create a union of the nested object's keys and the former key `K` itself.

```
[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Keys<T[K]> | K : K
```

Last, I generate a union of all those mentioned nested key unions using:

```
[keyof T]
```

Comment: Wow, amazing way of doing it. I'd love to give you credit, but the below hint that my version is basically working and just had typo just beats it :/

Comment: Okay, thank you for the compliment anyway :)